# ArrayList.addAll() ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java

I'm facing some really strange problems while implementing a kind of Kademlia bucket in Java 8 (OpenJDK).

I need to get at least a specific number of items from so-called Buckets.
But that's not the problem.

Somehow, I get sometimes a ConcurrentModificationException while doing closest.addAll() on the ArrayList though it is just used in a single thread and I'm not iterating or doing something like that.

Do you know how to help me?
Here is my code (I know it's a mess!):

```
List<Neighbour> getClosest(Node n, int num) {
    ArrayList<Neighbour> closest = new ArrayList<>();
    int missing;
    int walkDown = n.getBucket(me);
    int walkUp = walkDown + 1;
    boolean pleaseBreak = true;
    while (true) {
        missing = num - closest.size();
        if (missing <= 0) {
            return closest;
        }

        if (walkUp >= 0 && walkUp < 160) {
            List<Neighbour> l = buckets[walkUp].getClosest(missing);
            closest.addAll(l);
            if (closest.size() >= missing) {
                return closest;
            }
            walkUp++;
            pleaseBreak = false;
        }

        if (walkDown >= 0 && walkDown < 160) {
            List<Neighbour> l = buckets[walkDown].getClosest(missing);
            closest.addAll(l);
            if (closest.size() >= missing) {
                return closest;
            }
            walkDown--;
            pleaseBreak = false;
        }

        if (pleaseBreak) {
            return closest;
        }
        pleaseBreak = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What type is `buckets[walkDown]`? And can you show the code of `getClosest(missing)`?

Comment: this looks fine, please provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please post a stack trace.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterating through a Collection, avoiding ConcurrentModificationException when removing in loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/iterating-through-a-collection-avoiding-concurrentmodificationexception-when-re)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ConcurrentModificationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) actually means that you are breaking the rules  of iteration by somehow modifying the list while iterating it.

> Note that this exception does not always indicate that an object has been concurrently modified by a different thread. If a single thread issues a sequence of method invocations that violates the contract of an object, the object may throw this exception. **For example, if a thread modifies a collection directly while it is iterating over the collection** with a fail-fast iterator, the iterator will throw this exception.

That said it is fairly clear what could be causing this issue. As `closest` is a new `List` being filled by the method it must be `l` that is being modified.

There are two options:

1. Another thread is doing it.
2. You already have an iterator open across the list `l`.

Assuming it is not *1* (or you would probably have mentioned that) I will go for:

*Your `getClosest` method is returning a sublist of a list that is being iterated across and/or modified and `addAll` is also attempting to iterate over it.*

To fix, make `getClosest` return a **copy** of the sublist.

Comment: Thanks, I was such an idiot. Now, it's working fine, I'm just using a copy-constructor.

Comment: @Marcel - It's a common mistake. A copy constructor is a good solution.